# Descobrir tamanho da imagem que foi inserida por input file

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

Eu estou criando um sistema para organizar as imagens de um site, ou seja, vou armazenar informações como nome, extensão, tamanho, altura, largura, ... e estou com dificuldades para pegar os dados da altura e da largura

Os códigos atualmente são:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#file').on('change',function(e){

            var input = e.target;
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(){
          var dataURL = reader.result;
          $('#img').prop('src',dataURL);
          console.log($('#img'));
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

        var arquivo = input.files[0].name;
            var split = arquivo.split('.');
        var extensao = split[split.length-1];
        var nome = arquivo.replace('.'+extensao,'');
        var tamanho = (input.files[0].size/1024).toFixed(2);
        var altura = 'ainda não descobri';
        var largura = 'ainda não descobri';

        $('#arquivo').html('Arquivo: '+arquivo);
        $('#nome').html('Nome: '+nome);
        $('#extensao').html('Extensão: '+extensao);
        $('#tamanho').html('Tamanho: '+tamanho+' kB');
        $('#altura').html('Altura: '+altura);
        $('#largura').html('Largura: '+largura);
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<input id="file" type='file' accept='image/*'><br>
<br>
<p id="arquivo"></p>
<p id="nome"></p>
<p id="extensao"></p>
<p id="tamanho"></p>
<p id="altura"></p>
<p id="largura"></p>
<br>
<img id='img'>
```

Descobri que ao escrever `console.log($('#img'));` no onload faz com que apareça no console as informações da imagem, mas ao digitar `$('#img').width();` ou `$('#img').height();` o resultado passa a ser 0. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: tente o seguinte
var width = $('#img').naturalWidth;
var height = $('#img').naturalHeight;

Comment: Fica 'undefined' usando o natural...

Comment: Acredito que funcione somente após o carregamento da imagem

Comment: Consegui com o [0]. Ficou $('#img')[0].naturalWidth; e $('#img')[0].naturalHeight.

Comment: Mas só pega da segunda em diante...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após o carregamento da imagem você consegue obter esses valores através de suas propriedades, exemplo:

```
console.log($(img).prop('height'));
console.log($(img).prop('width'));
```

```js
$('#teste').load(function(){
   $("#height").html($(this).prop('height'));
    $("#width").html($(this).prop('width'));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="imagem">
  <img id="teste" src="http://www.google.hr/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
</div>
<div id="DadosDaImagem">
  <span id="height"></span>
  <span id="width"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Me ajudou a resolver o problema: Ficou assim: $('#img').on('load',function(){
     console.log($(this).prop('height'));
      console.log($(this).prop('width'));
    });